# Reversing arraylist not working properly

Tags: java, arraylist, reverse

My task is to read from an input file `test.txt`, this text has some sentences.
I need to write a class with a constructor and three methods.
One of which has to reverse the order of the words in a sentence.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class Reverser {


Scanner sc3 = null ;


//constructor takes input file and initialize scanner sc pointing at input
public Reverser(File file)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{



 sc3 = new Scanner (file); 
}



//this method reverses the order of the words in each line of the input
//and prints it to output file specified in argument.
public void reverseEachLine(File outpr)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

     // ArrayList<String> wordsarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

   while(sc3.hasNextLine()){
        String sentence = sc3.nextLine();
       // int length = sentence.length();
        String[] words =  sentence.split(" ");


       // wordsarraylist.clear();
        List<String> wordsarraylist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
        Collections.reverse(wordsarraylist);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outpr,true); 

        for(String str: wordsarraylist) {
            writer.write(str + " ");
           }

        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        writer.close();
    }


}


}
```

I have removed two other methods but they don't interfere with this one.
And this is my main:

```
import java.io.*;

public class DemoReverser {
    public static void main (String [] args)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Reverser r = new Reverser(new File("test.txt"));

        r.reverseEachLine(new File("out2.txt"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that at the end of the execution my output file contains the same thing. It is not reversing the order. How come? doesn't `Collections.reverse()` reverse the order? And so when I print it I should have the words in reverse?

I am also required to use arraylist.

This my input file:

```
This is just a small file. That
has some lines of text.
If we are successful, these
lines will be
reversed.
Let's hope for the best!
```

I am supposed to get this in my output:

```
That file. small a just is This
text. of lines some has
these successful, are we If
be will lines
reversed.
best! the for hope Let's
```

But i am getting this:

```
This is just a small file. That 
has some lines of text. 
If we are successful, these 
lines will be 
reversed. 
Let's hope for the best!
```

Comment: Please show sample input, sample output, expected output, and ideally fix your code formatting - the indentation is all oer the place at the moment. (It's not clear why you're recreating the output file on each iteration, by the way - why not keep the writer open for the whole time?)

Comment: The code works for me, by the way. With an input file of lines "first second" and "third fourth", I got an output file of "second first" and "fourth third", exactly as expected.

Comment: Tried it as well. It works for me too.

Comment: Check the code, it gives the expected output as require.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the method `reverseEachLine`, it works fine.  Don't construct `Scanner` at the constructor.

public class MyReverser {

```
private File inputFile;

public MyReverser(File file) {
    this.inputFile = file;
}

public void reverseEachLine(File outpr) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);

    ArrayList<List<String>> wordsarraylist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String sentence = sc.nextLine();

        List words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));
        Collections.reverse(words);
        wordsarraylist.add(words);
    }

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outpr, false);
    for (List<String> list : wordsarraylist) {
        for (String string : list) {
            writer.append(string + " ");
        }
        writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

}

I have answered here with full code [java cannot create file by 3 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752820/java-cant-create-file/32753258#32753258)